# First Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, project, code-first

I had installed and set up both Eclipse and Android needs. Even though, I did not make any change in code, I faced with some errors and could not see "Hello World" in my emulator. Can anyone helps me?

Comment: Post the errors and your code.

Comment: In Eclipse, click Window -> Show View -> LogCat. Try to run your program and you will likely see lots of red lines start to fly in the logcat. Copy and paste that in here as a start so we can see if it is something arbitrary.

Comment: @zgc7009 I can not see a LogCat option in the Show View Panel instead of this I see Error Log option. Is this a problem?

Comment: Is there an "other" option where you can look for the LogCat in a list?

Comment: @zgc7009 yes I found the LogCat option, however there is no red lines?

Comment: Did you run your application?

Comment: @zgc7009 yes I run my app but I see "Your project contains errors ..." mesagge but in LogCat panel there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the version of your system in AndroidManifest.
  Its possible of your emulator are an incompatible version.
- In eclipse go to Project > Clean > Clean All Projects
- Create new emulator

ps: Use Genymotion instead of native emulator.